# linux route table to collection of route commands

Tags: linux, shell-script

Is there any command or shell script to convert route table to route commands ?
For example this table :

```
> cat /proc/net/route   
Iface   Destination     Gateway         Flags   RefCnt  Use     Metric  Mask            MTU     Window  IRTT                                                       
wlan0   00000000        0101A8C0        0003    0       0       0       00000000        0       0       0                                                                              
eth0    0000000A        00000000        0001    0       0       0       000000FF        0       0       0                                                                               
eth0    640A0A0A        010A0A0A        0007    0       0       0       FFFFFFFF        0       0       0                                                                               
br-b5e0b6d6154d 00001414        00000000        0001    0       0       0       0000FFFF        0       0       0                                                                                                          
wlan0   00E14D33        0101A8C0        0003    0       0       600     00FFFFFF        0       0       0                                                                            
wlan0   0000FEA9        00000000        0001    0       0       1000    0000FFFF        0       0       0                                                                           
docker0 000011AC        00000000        0001    0       0       0       0000FFFF        0       0       0                                                                            
br-96a8372a5004 000013AC        00000000        0001    0       0       0       0000FFFF        0       0       0                                                                    
wlan0   00D48DB9        0101A8C0        0003    0       0       600     00FFFFFF        0       0       0                                                                            
wlan0   0001A8C0        00000000        0001    0       0       600     00FFFFFF        0       0       0                                                                            
wlan0   0101A8C0        00000000        0005    0       0       50      FFFFFFFF        0       0       0                                                                             
wlan0   0101A8C0        00000000        0005    0       0       600     FFFFFFFF        0       0       0
```

I want to convert this (or result of `route -n`) to collection of route commands .
Linux has something like iptables-save for route table ?

Answer (score 0):

`ip route help` points to the existence of `ip route save` and `ip route restore`, which can be used for exactly that.

Comment: this command dump routes as binary , is there any way to read that as ascii ?

Comment: Simply use "show" instead of "save". I pointed to "ip route help" so that you have an idea where to look yourself!